# How can I display special word for index array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, hour

I still newbie and faced with one challenge.

I want to display specific word in <**div**> when user wants to find out the **datetime**
for example:

```
let today = new Date;

let time = today.getHours()
let hours= [
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'fun',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'work',
    'fun',
    'fun',
    'fun',
    'work',
    'work',
    'fun',
    'fun',
    'fun',
    'fun',
  ]
let hoursName = hours[today.getHours()];
console.log(hoursName);
```

My code works, but it *a little bit not properly* I think.
If length of my array, in future,  will 999 indexes? To fill each index,  I'll spend many time, is it possible somehow add (**if, else if**) into array?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have an array with 24 entries, one entry per hour of the day. I can't see any pattern in this array. What would 999 entries mean? What's the pattern? How would you add `if, else if` to the array?

Comment: for example: I have an array it call [metres]. As you know in 1 metres = 100 centimeters or  1000 millimeters. And in order for not write 1000 indexes, I want to made up something identify (for example): from 245 to 321 = as value 'OK', indexes 1, 55, 79, 987 = as value 'GOOD'

Comment: I think what you need is an array of ranges and values like `[{rangeStart: a, rangeEnd: b, value: c}]` where *a*, *b* and *c* are appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array which contains the start and end index for "fun" values. Like for the 24 example in the question, It can be created as below:

```
var funRanges = [[7, 7], [15, 17], [21, 23]]; // [[Start, end]] (Both inclusive)
```

Then using a function, you can check if your hour value lies in any of the ranges. Like below:

```js
var funRanges = [[7, 7], [15, 17], [21, 23]]; // [[Start, end]] (Both inclusive)

var getHourName = (hour) => funRanges.some(x => hour >= x[0] && hour <= x[1]) ? 'fun': 'work';
console.log(getHourName(1))
// work
```

[image]

In future, You can just add new ranges into your rangeArray, and the code will still work fine.

Comment: What happens if there is a third category, e.g. "sleep"? It's much better to include code as a runnable snippet and not use images of code or results.

Comment: In that case, You can have series of predicates, each of which is responsible for one type of result. Inside each predicate, you can have above range function.

Comment: regarding the snippet, i have added it as code. I don't know how the runnable snippet can be created here. For sake of clarity, i had provided results as well.

Comment: Please use `let`/`const` instead of `var` in your answers: https://blog.usejournal.com/awesome-javascript-no-more-var-working-title-999428999994

Comment: @jabaa—the use of *var* or *let* is irrelevant to the answer. Many of the opinions at the referenced article are just that, opinions.

Comment: @RobG `var` is bad practice. Most static code analyzers and code reviews wouldn't accept it. What's the reason to use `var` today? Just because it's possible? `let`/`const` are better and for free.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain array of arrays and each sub array is window of "last index" and "type of item".

In the following same 
0-6 --> work 
7-7 --> fun 
8-23 --> movie

```js
const get = (index) => {
  // array of array, each array is "last index" and "type"
  const hours = [
    [6, "work"],
    [7, "fun"],
    [23, "movie"],
  ];
  const slot = hours.find((arr) => arr[0] >= index);
  return slot[1];
};

console.log(get(5));
console.log(get(7));
console.log(get(15));
```